# Is layer normaization always better than batch normalization for deep learning

Tags: normalization, deep-learning

The recently developed [Layer Normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450) method addresses the same problem as [Batch Normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167), but with lower computational overhead and no dependence on the batch so it can be applied consistently during training and testing.

My question is, is layer normalization always better than batch normalization, or are there still some cases where batch normalization can be beneficial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the paper of Layer Normalization it says that Batch Normalization works better for Convolutional neural networks. Therefore, it depends on the application type. It gives a reason for this: if each neuron gives similar contributions then shifting and scaling will work well, however, in convnets this is not the case, since at the boundaries of an image the activities of neurons are very different.
So try to apply it only to fully connected layers and RNN's. Although, at least for the former, BN could also potentially perform better than LN depending on the batch size and problem type.